# How to set up package-building?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, packaging

Though we are largely satisfied with the official packages provided by Ubuntu, some times we'd like to make a change (like adding a patch or upgrade version) to an existing package or even add a package of our own.

I come from the FreeBSD world, where this is handled by "ports" -- is there anything like it for Ubuntu?

Comment: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/

Comment: Thanks... Looks like `bzr` is still a requirement, as is registering with Launchpad -- because `bzr` can not do anonymous check-outs... Is that really true?..

Comment: TL;DR, what is the equivalent to `svn co https://svn.freebsd.org/ports` in Ubuntu world?

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what `svn co https://svn.freebsd.org/ports` means, so I can not answer. I had to look up what `TL;DR` means (too long, didn't read). O.K. so I can not help.

Comment: The svn-command quoted checks out the FreeBSD ports -- which are each very similar in nature (and identical in purpose) to the `debian/` subdirectory of each package ported to Debian. I'd like to similarly obtain the Ubuntu's package-tree, which would let me rebuild any package I wish...

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to try and start patching official Ubuntu software packages yourself. You'll end up with an unsupportable configuration.

Best to check the `backports` repository, or the `proposed` repository, for updated packages that may include a fix that you require.

If you have a specific fix or patch suggestion, it's best to submit it, and let them implement/test it, and then submit it upstream.

Comment: So, your answer to the question on how to do something is to not do it?

Comment: I didn't say that. I suggested not to create a patchwork of unsupportable software (if you expect a stable system), but to use the "official" paths to get to where you want. If you find a bug, or find software that needs enhancement, report it. Hey, patch source code for open software all you want, but don't necessarily expect support from the original author either.

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I make no mention of expecting support from the original author anywhere in my question. Indeed, it is rather questionable, what such "support" might entail in the FOSS world regardless of how one does builds...